# UIApplicationMain sigabrt appears on template app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I've made 10-20 different x-codeproject with the same name, saved in different locations. Now, every time I try to create a new project with this name, i get the error:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I googled the error, and found a lot of sites telling me that I have to implement a view or something like that. The case is that this error appears even if I create a project from a template (like windowbased app), name it with this name and then running it, without changing any of the code. If I name the app something else, it builds and runs perfectly. I've also noticed that naming a new project with this name, I also get a splash-image I've added in one of the other 10 projects, even though the targets summary tells me that the app hasn't got any spash-screens added.

Of course, I could just name the app something else, but I thought I should solve the problem, to make sure no other "errors" will occor later.

Comment: You've given the line of code at which the error occurs, not the error itself. Please look at the console log.

Comment: ***Couldn't register com.OurCompanyName.OurAppName with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c***


I've tried to reset the simulator, but it didn't help.

Comment: And this line of code also appeared: ***0x00020a8e  <+0643>  mov    0x50429f(%ebx),%eax***  I'm new to iOS, so i havn't got a clue about what this could be.

Comment: Your comment about the bootstrap server has been a bug in Xcode early on.  Clean all targets, clean the build folder, then restart Xcode. As for the whole 'view' thing, that's an outlet in the mainwindow xib that has to be connected to a view or view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is getting here and the comments above aren't working, this worked for me:

1. Clean
2. Clean build folder (hold opt under the build menu)
3. Reboot computer.